# Trying to add SonarQube - SonarAnalysis task in YAML build template for VSTS as a build task

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, azure-pipelines-build-task

Phase LibraryBuildGated: Step input SonarQube references endpoint 17xxxxc3-4xx0-4xx4-9xx2-617fxxxxxxxx which could not be found. The service endpoint does not exist or has not been authorized for use

Thanks
-Edited Question

Comment: On SonarQube server side, look at the background tasks administration page, and see if the processing of the analysis report was successful.

Comment: I currently don't have access to admin page to check background task - But I wonder why there is no documentation or steps listed any where to setup a sonar project  via YAML templates.
All I see is UI based examples
-- As far as what I see from VSTS build logs the analysis is successful and matches with the build warnings from Visual Studio build

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build). On the other hand, you can refer to these steps below to get YAML code: 1. Add a SonarQube analysis task 2. Specify necessary information 3. Click View YAML.

Comment: Thank you @starianchen-MSFT @Julien 
I the problem is with VSTS actually, 
**`Phase LibraryBuildGated: Step input SonarQube references endpoint 17xxxxc3-4xx0-4xx4-9xx2-617fxxxxxxxx which could not be found. The service endpoint does not exist or has not been authorized for use`**
Im clue less now

Comment: This is a limitation of YAML builds. When trying to reference a endpoint, you have to do it on the master branch. I guess you are experimenting the YAML build on a feature branch.

Comment: yes I'm on a feature branch and I'll be surprised if my ppl will let me experiment me on a master branch !!!!!!!!!! 
@JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-authz.md#resources

Comment: Thank you @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam

Answer (score 2):

**Prerequisites**

1. I have a SonarQube server setup in Azure on a Linux WebApp
2. I have installed the following Azure DevOps [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube
3. I have setup a SonarQube service connection ("SonarQube Service Connection") to my SonarQube server in Azure. You will find this option in Project Settings > Pipelines > Server Connections

**Prepare analysis on SonarQube in Yaml:**

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.15B84CA1-B62F-4A2A-A403-89B77A063157.SonarQubePrepare@4
  displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQube Service Connection'
    projectKey: ProjectKey
    projectName: ProjectName
```

**Run Code Analysis  in Yaml:**

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.6D01813A-9589-4B15-8491-8164AEB38055.SonarQubeAnalyze@4
  displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
```

**Publish Quality Gate Result  in Yaml:**

```
- task: SonarSource.sonarqube.291ed61f-1ee4-45d3-b1b0-bf822d9095ef.SonarQubePublish@4
  displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
```

Comment: Where did you get the sonarSource task names from? I am looking here and cannot see where to get information about setting up the task.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#utility

Comment: In answer to my previous comment, I realise you can select an existing pipeline task (created in the visual designer) and click 'view YAML' to see the task as YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
A workaround that covers most cases is, navigate to the build definition in the web, switch the default branch to your branch that includes the service endpoint reference, save, revert back to your desired settings, save again. The act of saving the definition loads the file (from the default branch) and authorizes discovered resources.
-suggested by MSFT